# When use resolveOperatorsUp and when use resolveOperatorsDown for the spark sql query analyzer

Tags: apache-spark

I am reading spark sql source code. I got one question that I would ask for a help/explanation.

Spark SQL defines a set of analysis rules in the `Analyzer#batches`.When applying the rules,
Spark SQL use `AnalysisHelper` defined two methods, one is `resolveOperatorsDown`, the other is `resolveOperatorsUp`. One is traversing the tree in pre-order,the other is in post-order.

When applying the rules to the tree by traversing recursively, I would ask when `resolveOperatorsDown` should be used, and when `resolveOperatorsUp` should be used

There are many analysis rules that are using `resolveOperatorsUp`,such as

`ResolveTempViews ResolveFunctions ResolveUpCast ResolveSubquery`.

Also,there are many that are using `resolveOperatorsDown`,such as
`ResolveCatalogs ExtractWindowExpressions ResolveCoalesceHints`

Thanks.